# How to merge json arrray with table (SQL Server)

Tags: json, sql-server, join

I have two rows of json that I would like to join on id into a single select.

**Sample Table A**

| a |
| --- |
| [{id: 1, name: "Alice"},{id:2, name: "Bob"}] |
| [{id: 5, name: "Charlie"},{id:6, name: "Dale"} |

**Sample Table B**

| id | age |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 |
| 2 | 32 |
| 3 | 20 |
| 4 | 14 |

**Desired Output**

| c |
| --- |
| [{id: 1, name: "Alice", age: 30},{id:2, name: "Bob", age: 32}] |
| [{id: 5, name: "Charlie", age: 20},{id:6, name: "Dale", age: 14}] |

I'd like to do something like

```
select 
id,
name, 
age
from openJson(tableA) ta
with (
  id int '$.id',
  name nvarchar(50) '$.name'
)
inner join (
  select *
  from tableB tb
) on tb.id = ta.id
for json path
```

Comment: OK, so what is your question? What isn't working about what you have?

Comment: Are you JSON field names not quoted?  I don't think `openjson` works with unquoted field names

Comment: So each row in TableA is a separate array?  It's just a typo in the second row that doesn't close the array in that row?

Comment: @squillman Yes.

Comment: @Larnu I'm unable to use `openJson` on multiple rows. (Would like to join each cell to another table).

Comment: *"'m unable to use openJson on multiple rows. "* Why can't you?

Comment: FYI, to even begin to consume your JSON though, it needs to be properly formatted, and yours is not; none of the element names are quoted.

Comment: Also, why is Charlie given the age of 20? Their ID in the JSON is 5, and there is no data with that ID in `tableB`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, this *assumes* that your JSON is actually valid. None of your elements (`id` and `name`) are quoted, so the JSON is actually invalid. Also I assume your expected results are wrong, as Charlie is give the age of 20, but that age belongs to someone with an `id` with the value `3`, and Charlie's has an `id` of `5`.

Anyway, we can can achieve this with a subquery:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableA (a nvarchar(MAX));
INSERT INTO dbo.TableA (a)
VALUES(N'[{"id": 1, "name": "Alice"},{"id":2, "name": "Bob"}]'),
      (N'[{"id": 5, "name": "Charlie"},{"id":6, "name": "Dale"}]');
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableB (id int, age int);
INSERT INTO dbo.TableB (id, age)
VALUES (1,30),
       (2,32),
       (3,20),
       (4,14);
GO

SELECT (SELECT OJ.id,
               OJ.[name],
               B.age
        FROM OPENJSON(A.a)
             WITH (id int,
                   [name] nvarchar(50)) OJ
             LEFT JOIN dbo.TableB B ON OJ.id = B.id
        FOR JSON AUTO) a
FROM dbo.TableA A;
     
     
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.TableA;
DROP TABLE dbo.TableB;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=52f4078c9d975eefb08df3c6f407af5b)